# How to catch values of checkboxes that are paginated with DataTables plugin

Tags: jquery, checkbox, datatables

I have table that looks like this: [image]

As you can see there are checkboxes next to users whose values I need to catch if they are checked. And I did it with this code before there were not enough users for pagination to work:

```
var cbChecked = new Array();
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function () {
      cbChecked[cbChecked.length] = this.value;
});
```

But since I'm using `DataTables` plugin, and pagination splits users, jQuery is only able to see those checkboxes that are displayed on current page, even though I have two more users checked on page 2 of my table. When I inspected page I see that in DOM there are really only these people displayed, others are not even hidden. Any suggestion what to do to catch all checked checkboxes in my table?

Comment: Poz Ognjen, go check [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/07Lrpqm7/), there you will see how to get all table rows from datatable instance. He used: `var rows = table.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();`, than `$('input[type="checkbox"]', rows)`

Comment: This helped, thanks a lot man.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question, it may help others.

Comment: use `$("input[type='checkbox']:checked", tableUsers.fnGetNodes()).each(function () {}` ...

Comment: already found solution, but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code that works for this type of problems:

```
var tableUsers = $('#showUsersTable').DataTable({
            searching:false,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bLengthChange": true,
            "bFilter": true,
            "bSort": false,
            "bInfo": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "bProcessing": true
        });
```

First instantiate DataTables. These properties are not important, I needed them for other stuff.

```
var rows = tableUsers.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();
```

This variable `rows` contains all `td` elements, even if they are not displayed on the page and are invisible in DOM.

```
            $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).each(function(i,e){
                $(e).change(function(){
                    var checkBoxC = [];
                    var cbChecked = new Array();
                    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked', rows).each(function(o,a){
                        checkBoxC[checkBoxC.length]=$(a).val();
                        $.each(checkBoxC, function(h, el){
                            if($.inArray(el, cbChecked) === -1) cbChecked.push(el);
                        });
                    });
                    $("input#cbChecked").val(cbChecked.join());
                });
            });
```

Since `cbChecked` is declared inside `change` function I needed to put it's value into hidden DOM element(`input#cbChecked`), so I could use it out of scope of change function.